# Use of the phrase ‘Such as’ to begin a sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence, context, such

Is the second sentence below grammatically correct in the context of the first sentence? I.e. can I commence a sentence with the phrase ‘Such as’?

> You can access personal details we hold about you. Such as medical records, payments history or information relating to claims and appeals.

Answer (score 1):

> Such as medical records, payments history or information relating to claims and appeals.

This is a phrase without a predicate. Since there's no predicate, it's an incomplete / invalid sentence. Such as acts as a connection between an idea, such as a direct object, and a list of examples that describe or provide some clarification, scope, or depth to it; however, a list without a predicate describing some action is hardly accepted a complete sentence. Usually the only widely used nominal sentences are imperatives and exclamatory things where a subject or predicate are implied.

> You can access personal details we hold about you, such as medical records, payments history or information relating to claims and appeals.

Note the comma is necessary to facilitate the non-restrictive phrase.

This is a bit awkward, though. The examples are far after the object they describe, and partitioned by an entire adjective phrase.

> You can access personal details we hold about you. This data includes medical records, payments history, and information relating to claims and appeals.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't break the sentence into two by placing a full stop (period) before "such as" because the phrase beginning with "such as" is an adjectival phrase modifying the collection or concept defined in the first part of the sentence (or, in your example, the first sentence).

Sentences are expressions of concepts and you should only start a new sentence when the concept changes in some way. In the case of a sentence with the phrase "such as" in it the description of the concept and the list of examples are different aspects of the same concept so should be part of the same sentence.

If the list of examples is long or you want to emphasise the contents of the list in a display **such as** a leaflet, poster or web page you can use an indented or numbered list. In your example this might become:

> You can access personal details we hold about you such as

> medical records,

> payments history or

> information relating to claims and appeals.

If you have a very long or complex list and want to start a separate sentence you should start the second sentence with a different phrase. For example you could write

> You can access personal details we hold about you. These personal details may include medical records, payments history or information relating to claims and appeals.

You would still be referring back to the concept defined in the first sentence but, by restating the concept, you are separating the list from the statement of the concept and not using an adjectival phrase to start the second sentence